# PHP: sending parameters to a webservice via url and getting response

Tags: php, web-services, forms, request, response

I know how obtain info from a webservice: connecting (sending url, user and pass) and calling a method passing parameters to it using nusoap. Here's and example:

```
$client = new nusoap_client($webServiceURL, 'wsdl', $proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);

    $session_header = "<UserCredentials xmlns='http://page.net/Webservice/'><Userid>".$username."</Userid><Password>".$password."</Password></UserCredentials>";
    $client->setHeaders($session_header);

    $params = array('param_a'=> $var_a, 'param_b'=> $var_b);

    $result = $client->call('nameOfMethod', $params);
```

But what I don't know is how to send info via url given this:

I have a registration form,  and once it is submited I have to send:

Request:
[base_path]/register/[name]/[address]/[email]/[phone]

Response:

OK  (is registered):
header content: 200;
body content xml:

Fields: [pass]

KO (is not registered):
header content: 401;
body content XML:

```
<response>
<error>
[error number]
</error>
</response>
```

Fields: [error number]

Knowing this, please follow me through it, what do I have to do after the form is submitted? As you see,  I'm  quite new to it and I'm totally lost. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying using SOAP, and I was wrong  (sorry I'm learning). What I am doing here is creating a REST request.

I've done so far:

```
$request = "http://path.com/app/register/".$phone."/".$gender."/".$address."/". $name;
$response = file_get_contents($request);
```

But when I print the response I get:
1d1ffaf569a8a6b3ddc5e88c1c219c22

When I should be getting a 200 in the headers and an xml in the body if the response is OK.

When the response is KO, I'm getting it right:

```
<response>
<error>
[error number]
</error>
</response>
```

What is happening with the OK response? I get it because of file_get_contents?

If so, what else can I use? I heard of cURL but have no idea on how to use it :(

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand you question but maybe this can help you:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

or even directly using simplexml: 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-file.php